# Rails 5 paperclip images not showing up

Tags: image, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

Images are not showing up, only a small image icon. When I inspect the image I get the following path: `<img src="/system/protests/images/000/000/001/thumb/no_cuny_cuts.jpg?1500589981" alt="No cuny cuts">` I believe I have to set the path to look into the public folder since the URL of the image starts at `system`. I have tried to use all the questions posted on this but had no luck. Here are the files.

model
protest.rb

```
class Protest < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :description, :location,
            :starts_at, :creator, presence: true

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "400x600#" }, default_url: "/images/default_:style_avatar.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  belongs_to :creator, class_name: :User

  has_many :attendances
  has_many :users, through: :attendances

  has_many :transportations
end
```

config/application.rb

```
module ProtestTrump
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Don't generate system test files.
    config.generators.system_tests = nil

    #paperclip
    config.paperclip_defaults = { storage: :fog, fog_credentials: { provider: "Local", local_root: "#{Rails.root}/public"}, fog_directory: "", fog_host: "localhost"}
  end
end
```

migration

```
class AddImageColumnsToProtests < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
   add_attachment :protests, :image
  end

  def down
   remove_attachment :protests, :image 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why this didn't work. As you can see in the model/protest.rb the following line

`has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "400x600#" }, default_url: "/images/default_:style_avatar.png"`

Here you need to add thumb: if you want to use it. So you have to change this line to add thumb styles.

`has_attached_file :image, styles: {thumb: "100x100#", medium: "400x600#" }, default_url: "/images/default_:style_avatar.png"`.
After adding `thumb:`

to the styles you have to reset the model.
I ran the following command

`bundle exec rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails CLASS=Protest`

The instructions for reset can be found in the following link.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation